# Integrating PubNub into Swift Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, pubnub

I am building a Swift framework that I hope to ultimately have universally accessible through cocoapods, carthage, etc.

My Framework relies on `PubNub` networking and their `Realtime iOS SDK` (Objective C).

I have tried dropping the Source Code into my framework, but I can't create a bridging header in a framework since it is not supported by Apple.

How would a developer go about adding Objective C source code to a Swift SDK, and if possible - `PubNub` specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Cocoapods's `dependency` if the lib can install through cocoapods or `vendored_library/vendored_framework` if they come in package, and I dont think you can add obj-c in Swift SDK

If you use `dependency`, cocoapods will install the other SDK as external lib, so you wont have any problem using your swift source depends on obj-c lib

Comment: Thank you for your response. I received a similar answer from PubNub developers. My concern here is ease of integration for my SDK and maintaining updated source code throughout all my libraries.

Can I ensure that all cocoapods within my own cocoapod will remain up to date and installed by simply adding 'MySDK' to the PodFile.

Does this go against Apple's recommendation to not create umbrella frameworks?

Comment: The update part is user job, you cant really control that, and once they update your SDK, of course your dependency framework will also get updated, so it fine